# Trying to conditionally disable multiple input fields for a carousel type app - The next button should be disabled if input field is empty

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, conditional-operator

First of all I apologise if this question has been asked over and over.

I have searched but I cannot find the answer in vanilla javascript for my scenario.

I am doing a challenge and have built a slider/carousel type app with 2 buttons, one for next slide and one for previous slide.

Some of the slides(divs) have input fields and I want to add a condition that if any of the input fields are empty then the 'next' button should be disabled.

I've set up an 'input' eventListener on the input fields and tried looping over the input fields as below.

```
nextButton.disabled = true;
inputs.forEach((input) =>
  input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    inputs.forEach((value) =>
      value.value != ""
        ? (nextButton.disabled = false)
        : (nextButton.disabled = true)
    );
  })
);
```

However, I just can't get it to work properly. I can't get the input field to re-enable this way and when I try to click on it it doesn't remove the disabled attribute from the button.

Could someone let me know why this might be happening and what I need to do to get it to disabled each input when the field is empty and enable the button when not.  Do I need to add a counter like I did for the carousel, so it know which input field to re-enable?.

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if you need anymore info.

```js
const previousButton = document.querySelector("#previousButton");
const nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextButton");
const slideContainer = document.querySelector(".slides");
const slide = document.querySelector(".slide");
const slides = slideContainer.children;
const greeting = document.querySelectorAll(".greeting");
const firstName = document.querySelector(".firstname");
const lastName = document.querySelector(".lastname");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const connectAccBtn = document.querySelector(".connectAccount");
console.log(inputs.forEach((item) => item.value));

let currentSlide = 0;
//****sliding info*****

const handleChanges = () => {
  currentSlide === slides.length - 2 ?
    (nextButton.remove(), previousButton.remove()) :
    (nextButton.style.opacity = 1);

  currentSlide > 0 && currentSlide < slides.length - 2 ?
    (previousButton.style.opacity = 1) :
    (previousButton.style.opacity = 0);
  slideContainer.style.marginLeft = `-${currentSlide}00vw`;
};

const previousSlide = () => {
  if (currentSlide > 0) {
    currentSlide -= 1; //could also use --
    handleChanges();
  }
};

const nextSlide = () => {
  if (slides[currentSlide + 1]) {
    currentSlide += 1; //could also use ++
    handleChanges();
  }
};
// ****main**********
const budgetScreen = () => {
  greeting.forEach((item) => (item.innerHTML = `hello ${firstName.value}`));

};

budgetScreen();

previousButton.addEventListener("click", previousSlide);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
firstName.addEventListener("change", budgetScreen);
connectAccBtn.addEventListener("click", budgetScreen);

nextButton.disabled = true;
inputs.forEach((input) =>
  input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    inputs.forEach((value) =>
      value.value != "" ?
      (nextButton.disabled = false) :
      (nextButton.disabled = true)
    );
  })
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #EBECF0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  /*     stops the slide show scrolling */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #EBECF0;
}

.buttons {
  /*     position: fixed; */
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#previousButton {
  opacity: 0;
}

.buttonButton {
  margin: 1rem;
  background: rgba( 4, 48, 114, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 4, 48, 114, 0.6)
}

.slides {
  transition: all 3s;
  display: flex;
  /*  height:90vh; */
}

h3 {
  color: #043072;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 25vw;
  background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
}

select {
  background: #EBECF0;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #043072;
  padding: 25px 25px;
}

.connectAccount {
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba( 4, 48, 114, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 4, 48, 114, 0.6);
}

input {
  display: flex;
  align-text: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 4px 2px 10px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
  /*   scroll-behavior: smooth; */
  overflow: none;
}

#slide_1,
#slide_2,
#slide_3,
#slide_4,
#slide_5,
#slide_6 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #EBECF0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slides">
      <div id="slide_2" class="slide">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Affordable</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Tell us your first name</h3>
          <input class="firstname inputField" type="text" name="first-name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="slide_3" class="slide">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Affordable</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Tell us your Last name</h3>
          <input class="inputField" type="text" name="lastname" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="slide_4" class="slide">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Affordable</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Whats your Email Address</h3>
          <input class="inputField" type="text" name="email" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="slide_5" class="slide">
        <div class="header budgetPage">
          <h1>Affordable</h1>
        </div>
        <h3 class="greeting">hello</h3>
        <button class="connectAccount"><a href='#slide_6'>Connect Your Account</a></button>
      </div>

      <div id="slide_6" class="slide">
        <div class="header budgetPage">
          <h1>Affordable</h1>
        </div>
        <h3 class="greeting">Welcome</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">

    <button id="previousButton" class="buttonButton" type="button">
      Previous </button>

    <button type="button" id="nextButton" class="buttonButton">Next</button>
  </div>
  <script src="budgetapp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tiropufoka/edit?js,output

Comment: Wow thanks, I started trying to use currentSide and didn't think to add it to the querySelector. I'll study the code a bit more tomorrow. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simple ways to test your project mate!
I haven't got much time but a quick console debugging showing that:

> ReferenceError: activeSlide is not defined

(on line 36)

also, and this is from a real quick look, it seems like here:

```
        inputs.forEach((input) =>
  input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    inputs.forEach((value) =>
      value.value != ""
        ? (nextButton.disabled = false)
        : (nextButton.disabled = true)
    );
  })
);
```

your'e checking whether **each and every** input is empty or not (you also forgot a **{** for the arrow function at beginning and end). if it wasn't your goal, I might suggest:

```
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
     input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
         this.value != ""
           ? (nextButton.disabled = false)
           : (nextButton.disabled = true);
     })
   });
```

notice how i changed the arrow function to an anonymous function that allows you to use **this**. in arrow function if you'd try use **this** you'd get the window object, whereas now you get the input field that you just binded the eventlistener to (for example: console.log(this) right above input.value != "", will return now an input object named "firstname" and not the window object).

Comment: Sorry yes I noticed I had left activeSlide in the code and had edited and changed the question to reflect, so that parts ok now.I tried the code and it  works for the first field however it then enables the button for all the input fields regardless of whether the field is empty.  However I only want to enable it for the first field when I input something. Then the same for the next field only when I input something and so on. Otherwise the input fields should stay disabled.

Comment: yes i think i understand your goal. Check out the second half of my comment above ^^

The eventlisteners binding of yours got  little messy, for a few reasons (that I spot):
1. you looped through inputs twice instead of once.
2. you can actually replace the arrow function with an anonymous one (like in my comment) and then use the reserved keyword *this*, which automatically represents the input object you're binding to the keyup event. It should work for your purpuse. for more information about this, check out: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

tell me if there's anything else:)

Comment: about the second loop, to make sure i explain what i mean: 
the logic you wrote is: upon **any** input keyup event > if the (basically) last input field is empty, disable nextbutton

Comment: I see what you mean. I got into a bit of loop hell, I only really needed to loop over the input fields and then add the eventlistener.  @blessenm also gave me a solution using e.target so will have a play with both. thanks for taking the time out to explain. :-)